# Is there an example that $\mathcal{O}(\mathrm{Proj}\,B)\neq B_0$ for some graded ring $B$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Is there  a graded ring $B=\bigoplus_{d\in \Bbb N}B_d$ such that  $\mathcal{O}(\mathrm{Proj}\,B)\neq B_0$?

Comment: Although the Question seems to lack context, the OP has provided such in the form of a self-answer below, so I'm voting to leave open.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, see for example Vakil's [Foundations of Algebraic Geometry](http://math.stanford.edu/~vakil/216blog/index.html), Exercise 7.3.J, which says in part "If $R$ is an $A$-algebra, define a graded ring $S_{\bullet}$ by $S_{0} = A$, and $S_{n} = R$ for $n > 0$. Describe an isomorphism $\operatorname{Proj} S_{\bullet} \simeq \operatorname{Spec} R$." So in this case we would have $\mathcal{O}(\operatorname{Proj}B) = R$ while $B_{0} = A$.

See also Görtz and Wedhorn's "Algebraic Geometry I", Remark 13.7 and the paragraph preceding it: "Let $A$ be a graded ring. The first kind of functoriality is the observation that that we may 'thin out' $A$ and 'change $A_{0}$' without changing the scheme $\operatorname{Proj}A$."

For a more "naturally occurring" example see [Global sections of $\mathrm{Proj\,} A[T_0,\ldots,T_n]/\langle T_i T_j\rangle$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2155782).

Answer (score 2):

I have gotten an answer by myself.
Let $B$ be a nonzero commutative ring. Given a trival grading for $B$, that is, let $B_0=B$, $B_d=0$ for $d\gt 0$, then $\mathcal{O}(\mathrm{Proj}\,B)=0\neq B_0$.